# Is inline javascript garbage collected when document body is replaced?

Tags: javascript, html, garbage-collection

Consider I have the below webpage written in HTML (body section only):

```
<body>
    <p>
        ...
    </p>

    <script>
        function fn() {
            // do stuff
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Now, if I replace the `innerHTML` of `document.body` from JavaScript with say, a div, so that the body part becomes:

```
<body>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

... then is the `fn` object *eligible* for garbage collection if no references to it exist anywhere in the rest of the code (any context)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be subject to garbage collection if no other references were made to it from any context. However, there is one small reference that is holding on to that function, the global window object.  This is because the function (and entire script section shown) is scoped globally. This reference will still exist *even if* the entire document.body's innerHTML is replaced.

There are only a few ways to free the object shown in your exact example from the global object and make it *eligible* for collection.  Deleting the property on the global object is not an option because it was declared as a function and not as a property.

- Overwrite the property on the global object with something else. `window.fn = [][0];` (undefined shortcut)
- Navigate away from the page so that the global object becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Quick note on garbage collection, it occurs when the browser feels that it is necessary, and *not* immediately after an object has no references (or at least, not usually - this may happen from time to time).

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this out, and interestingly, no.

http://jsfiddle.net/wah754La/1/

Test code:

body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo () {
        // i exist!
    }
</script>
```

and on load, this is run:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
console.log(foo);
// logs 'function foo()'
```

Comment: The function declaration creates a function object which is semantically separate from contents of the `script` tag and stores a reference to that function object in variable `foo`; as long as that variable holds that reference, the function object must continue to exist.  That says nothing, however, about whether any "standalone" JavaScript statements would have to continue to exist in any form, nor whether any representation of them would be kept alive if the function objects were replaced.